# Why my Spring Kafka unit test almost ran into ProducerFencedException every time

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions, kafka-transactions-api

The test is consist of 2 test cases

```
@Test
@Nested
inner class Test1 {
   fun test1() {
     mypublisher.publishInTransaction(topic1)  // see log1
     // check listener1  // see log2
   }
}

@Test
@Nested
inner class Test2 {
   fun test2() {
     mypublisher.publishInTransaction(topic2)  // see log3
     // check listener2
   }
}

fun MyPublisher.publishInTransaction() {
  // it is kafkatemplate instance
  producerOnlyKafkaTemplate.executeInransaction {
    producerOnlyKafkaTemplate.send(xxxx)
  }
}
```

test1 run before test2, log is in time order

log1

```
[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : Created new Producer: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] []
[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] beginTransaction() []
[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] send(ProducerRecord())
[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] commitTransaction() []
 2023-05-30 12:14:26.913  [Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] close(PT5S) []
```

log2

```
[Processor-0-C-1] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : Created new Producer: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@671afc6b] []
xxx this happened inside listener and the verification passed
```

log3

```
it reuses the producer created in log1, the gap is around 32seconds

 2023-05-30 12:14:58.206  [Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] beginTransaction() []
[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] send(ProducerRecord(xx))

[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] commitTransaction() []


[kafka-network-thread-test-txn-TX-0] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-ruis-MacBook-Pro-2.local-test-txn-TX-0, transactionalId=ruis-MacBook-Pro-2.local-test-txn-TX-0] Enqueuing transactional request AddPartitionsToTxnRequestData(transactionalId='ruis-MacBook-Pro-2.local-test-txn-TX-0', producerId=0, producerEpoch=0, topics=[AddPartitionsToTxnTopic(name="*", partitions=[0])]) []

Sending ADD_PARTITIONS_TO_TXN request with header RequestHeader

Received ADD_PARTITIONS_TO_TXN response from node 0 for request with xxx results=[AddPartitionsToTxnPartitionResult(partitionIndex=0, errorCode=90)])]) []

o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-ruis-MacBook-Pro-2.local-test-txn-TX-0, transactionalId=ruis-MacBook-Pro-2.local-test-txn-TX-0] Transiting to fatal error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: There is a newer producer with the same transactionalId which fences the current one. []


[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : commitTransaction failed: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] []
[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] close(PT5S) []
[Test worker] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : Error during some operation; producer removed from cache: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@58bb6ba7] []
```

it looks to me the producer@58bb6ba7 in log1, has comitted and got a newer epoch, however it is reused by test2(log3) with a lower epoch, what could be the problem?

the ENV is

```
spring-kafka-test 3.0.6
```

Updated (2023/May/31)

In this case I see the `MyProducerOnlyFactory` bean is called twice(it should be singleton), hence I have
`myproducer-txnid` linked to two `MyProducerOnlyFactory` instances.

with `MyProducerOnlyFactory-1` I get `myproducer-txnid-0`, commit transaction and return it to cache.

later on, in another listener thread, a kafkatemplate with `MyProducerOnlyFactory-2` find the above producer instance from cache, commit transaction and update producerepoch to 1

after that `MyProducerOnlyFactory-1` get back the `myproducer-txnid-0`, it thinks it is still epoch=0, commit transaction but get ProducerFencedException of course.

I fixed the issue with

```
@NestedTestConfiguration(NestedTestConfiguration.EnclosingConfiguration.OVERRIDE)
@SpringBootTest(xxx)
class MyNestedIntegrationTest {
  //xxx
}
```

with that I can see the `MyProducerOnlyFactory` bean initialised once only.

Comment: Please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I suggest you add an answer to this effect (you can then accept it a couple of days later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I see the `MyProducerOnlyFactory` bean is called twice(it should be singleton), hence I have `myproducer-txnid` linked to two `MyProducerOnlyFactory` instances.

with `MyProducerOnlyFactory-1` I get `myproducer-txnid-0`, commit transaction and return it to cache.

later on, in another listener thread, a kafkatemplate with `MyProducerOnlyFactory-2` find the above producer instance from cache, commit transaction and update producerepoch to 1

after that `MyProducerOnlyFactory-1` get back the `myproducer-txnid-0`, it thinks it is still epoch=0, commit transaction but get ProducerFencedException of course.

I fixed the issue with `NestedTestConfiguration`

```
@NestedTestConfiguration(NestedTestConfiguration.EnclosingConfiguration.OVERRIDE)
@SpringBootTest(xxx)
class MyNestedIntegrationTest {
  //xxx
}
```

with that I can see the `MyProducerOnlyFactory` bean initialised once only.